# Angular Universal, Meta Tags, copy link, paste to social AZURE MSAL AUTHENTICATION crypto_nonexistent: The crypto object or function is not available

Tags: angular, angular-cli, server-side-rendering, meta-tags, angular-universal

I have a web site which is an online shop, and the customer wants so that whenever they copy a link of the product that they are currently seeing, to paste it to Facebook, WhatsApp or other social media pages, they want to get that data stored on the product link and to show them as a product and not just the domain page to be shown.

Quick info, the front end page is made in Angular 11, the back end is made with .NET Core I think V5, the page is store on Azure Websites, and the images are stored on AWS S3.

The problem now is that I have tried almost everything on the front end side, Adding the Meta Tags on the index.html from the Meta Service that Angular provides, updating them every time another product is seen. I also saw that I have to add

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.am-clothes.com/shop/product/no/sidebar/12147218">
```

But the problem with this is that, whenever I change route, there is added another link rel that is not related to the product, I do not know how can I delete the old link rels on that. I will show you an example:

[image: This is tag link rel canonical is added every time I change route, that is the way I have made it.]

This is tag link rel canonical is added every time I change route, that is the way I have made it.

Is there any way I can remove any link rel tag that has canonical before adding another one? I have created a service which includes this code, but this code does not update the canonical link but adds another one:

```js
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';


@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CanonicalService {


constructor(
@Inject(DOCUMENT) private dom
) { }


setCanonicalURL(url?: string) {
if (url) {
console.log(url.split('/').join('/'))
}
// const remove: HTMLLinkElement = this.dom.remove('link');
const canURL = url == undefined ? this.dom.URL : 'https://www.am-clothes.com' + url;
const link: HTMLLinkElement = this.dom.createElement('link');
// link.removeAttribute('canonical');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'canonical');
link.setAttribute('href', canURL);
this.dom.head.appendChild(link);
}
}
```

Every time the route changes I call setCanonicalURL, but this adds new URLs every time it changes and it does not update it so I think that this might be one of the issues. The one I have tried to remove it from the code I tried it didn't work.

Now I am going to show you how I update Meta Tags dynamically.

Every time the product page is shown, I call Update metatags immediately with the Meta service that Angular provides, here is an example:

```js
this.metaService.updateTag(
{
property: 'og:image',
content: this.productDataFromAPI.images[0].imageUrls[0], 
}
);
this.metaService.updateTag(
{
name: 'title',
content: this.product.pershkrimiShkurter
}
);
this.metaService.updateTag(
{
name: 'og:title',
content: this.product.pershkrimiShkurter
}
);
this.metaService.updateTag(
{
name: 'description',
content: this.product.pershkrimi
}
);
this.metaService.updateTag(
{
name: 'keywords',
content: this.product.pershkrimi
}
);
this.metaService.updateTag(
{
property: 'og:description',
content: this.product.pershkrimi
}
);
this.metaService.updateTag(
{
property: 'og:type',
content: 'product'
}
);
this.metaService.updateTag(
{
property: 'product:original_price:amount',
content: this.product.cmimiMeZbritje.toString()
}
);
this.metaService.updateTag(
{
property: 'product:original_price:currency',
content: 'EUR'
}
);
this.metaService.updateTag(
{
property: 'product:price:amount',
content: this.product.cmimiMeZbritje.toString()
}
);
this.metaService.updateTag(
{
property: 'product:price:currency',
content: 'EUR'
}
);
```

And this code adds all the meta tags that I have written to the head element on index, here they are:

[image: These are all the meta tags that I have written above the image]

These are all the meta tags that I have written above the image.

[You can try and check A single product and view the meta tags and other stuff on the inspect element by clicking here.](https://www.am-clothes.com/shop/product/no/sidebar/12147218)

This is how it looks like when I paste the link that you are about to visit on Facebook or other page:
[image: Here must show Product image, product price, and many other stuff.]

Here must show Product image, product price, and many other stuff.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? Do I have to do something else? Is there needed any changes on the backend? What should I do to fix this?

Any help would be very much appreciated, since I am really stuck here for almost a month now, and I am at the final phase of the project, while without this it wouldn't be done.

EXTRA: After some other research, I saw that I have to go after the Angular Universal SSR. I do not have any experience to it but what I was trying is to run `npm run dev:ssr` which runs this command `ng run multikart:serve-ssr`, and it gives me this error: `ReferenceError: WheelEvent is not defined`

I have added a line on the global['WheelEvent'] = win.Event, but still without success, this is my server.ts file:

```js
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Load `$localize` onto the global scope - used if i18n tags appear in Angular templates.
 */
import '@angular/localize/init';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

// Refrence Error Event Not Found Solution
global['Event'] = null;

// Refrence Error Window Not found  solution
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../', '', 'browser/index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['Node'] = win.Node;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
global['Event'] = win.Event;
global['KeyboardEvent'] = win.Event;
global['MouseEvent'] = win.Event;
global['Event']['prototype'] = win.Event.prototype;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['WheelEvent'] = win.Event;
// global['window'] = win;
// global['document'] = win.document;
// global['navigator'] = win.navigator;

// Refrence Error localStorage Not found  solution
import 'localstorage-polyfill'
global['localStorage'] = localStorage;

const cors = require('cors');

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  server.use(cors());
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/multikart/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
  const LAZY_MODULE_MAP = require('./src/main.server');
  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
    providers: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  
  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, 
      providers: [{ 
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
        useValue: req.baseUrl 
      }]
    });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

Now I am stuck with this error, while I cannot find any solution to it.
If I run `ng build --prod && ng run multikart:server:production`, it builds successfully, but I can not test it live if I do not `run dev:ssr` as this throws an error.

Edit: [One thing that I found now is that this might be caused by this plugin.](https://github.com/bfwg/ngx-drag-scroll/issues/263)

I will look forward on to disable this and see what I will get.

After I removed that plugin, the error is gone, I can now run dev:ssr, but, since I use Azure MSAL login to authenticate the users.

This is the error that I am facing right now:

```js
BrowserAuthError: crypto_nonexistent: The crypto object or function is not available. Detail:Browser crypto or msCrypto object not available.
    at BrowserAuthError.AuthError [as constructor] (C:\Users\miloo\Documents\Projects\Jobs\AM-Clothes\frontend\multikart-ssr\dist\multikart\server\main.js:67103:24)
    at new BrowserAuthError (C:\Users\miloo\Documents\Projects\Jobs\AM-Clothes\frontend\multikart-ssr\dist\multikart\server\main.js:73530:28)
    at Function.Czdx.BrowserAuthError.createCryptoNotAvailableError (C:\Users\miloo\Documents\Projects\Jobs\AM-Clothes\frontend\multikart-ssr\dist\multikart\server\main.js:73547:16)
    at new BrowserCrypto (C:\Users\miloo\Documents\Projects\Jobs\AM-Clothes\frontend\multikart-ssr\dist\multikart\server\main.js:73810:36)
    at new CryptoOps (C:\Users\miloo\Documents\Projects\Jobs\AM-Clothes\frontend\multikart-ssr\dist\multikart\server\main.js:74179:30)
    at PublicClientApplication.ClientApplication (C:\Users\miloo\Documents\Projects\Jobs\AM-Clothes\frontend\multikart-ssr\dist\multikart\server\main.js:76129:30)
    at new PublicClientApplication (C:\Users\miloo\Documents\Projects\Jobs\AM-Clothes\frontend\multikart-ssr\dist\multikart\server\main.js:77123:23)
    at Object.MSALInstanceFactory [as useFactory] (C:\Users\miloo\Documents\Projects\Jobs\AM-Clothes\frontend\multikart-ssr\dist\multikart\server\main.js:105987:12)
    at Object.factory (C:\Users\miloo\Documents\Projects\Jobs\AM-Clothes\frontend\multikart-ssr\dist\multikart\server\main.js:131389:38)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (C:\Users\miloo\Documents\Projects\Jobs\AM-Clothes\frontend\multikart-ssr\dist\multikart\server\main.js:131300:35)
```

Comment: i m facing the same issue, i totally agree the plugin wil possibly be the culprit.

Comment: @MrBeast I did remove that, and that is gone now, I am facing another issue.

Comment: The og-tags are being cached by Facebook, Twitter, ... You may have to request a reindex, but I'd have to lookup the page to do so...

Comment: [Here's the link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). Paste your url, lookup, and click **Scrape again**